# How do i fix the following Python error: no module named Playback?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to run a script that was given to me and when i try to run it, I am given the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\XX\Documents\XX\Project\Experiments\Y-Maze\Data\M06\ymaze_working_script1.py", line 74, in <module>

from playback import Playback

ImportError: No module named playback
```

Code that this error is from:

```
#################################################################
### DON'T EDIT FROM HERE ###
from ymaze_track import MouseTracker
from ymaze_mark import Marker
from ymaze_track import FileHandler
import os
import csv
 import numpy as np
 import time
 from tkFileDialog import askopenfilenames
 import sys
 import Tkinter as tk
 from playback import Playback
```

Is playback a module that needs to be added to python or is inbuilt in? and if so - where can I find it?

Comment: `pip install playback`

Comment: Can you post the code snippet you are trying to run.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you want help with a problem, you need to be able to describe it for people to help you. That explanation usually involves showing the part of the code where the problem happens. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`playback` is not a standard python module so you must add it to your own system python modules

You can do this with run `pip install playback`

If you got other errors same as the error you described you can find package installation command by
searching in https://pypi.org/

And if your python code has requirement text file which most of the times named
**requirements.txt**

You can run `pip install -r requirements.txt`

For installing all needed package easily

Comment: To do this, should i have a file called "playback" to install? On previous occassions when I installed other modules I had to input the file name of the module that I wanted to install along with the pip command in the command line.

Comment: clicked on both the "check" and the "upvote" arrow but it wont affect the upvote arrow because my reputation is too low

Answer (score 0):

`playback` is not a standard python module, so you have to install it to use it. Run this command from the command line:

```
pip install playback
```

If that doesn't work, this should:

```
py -m pip install playback
```

[Here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/python-pip-usage) is a tutorial on using `pip` to install python modules.